# Is there any way to use connect of Redux for multiple components in the same file?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

As far as i know, connect() of Redux only allow one rendered component inside it. But i have 3 components in a same js file, and all of them need to access redux state as well as use dispatchs through actionCreator. But you can only use export default once in a file. My code kinda looks like this:

```html
...
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as Actions from '../redux/actions';-->my actionCreator file, don't notice it

const componentA=(props)=>{
  //do some dispatch here
  return(
  //render something here
  <componentB/>
  <Text>{props.state1}</Text> -->
)}

const componentB=(props)=>{
  //do some dispatch here
  return(
  //render something here
  <componentC/>
  <Text>{props.state2}</Text> -->props.state2 can't be accessed here
)}

const componentC=(props)=>{
  //do some dispatch here
  return(
  //render something here
  <Text>{props.state3}</Text> -->props.state3 can't be accessed here
)}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        state1: state.state1,
        state2: state.state2,
        state3: state.state3
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, Actions)(componentA); -->Here is the problem,
```

i can put only one component here.
Because componentA is parent so i put it there
hence the other two can not access redux state as well as the actionCreator

Answer (score 0):

you can use connect with other components like this without the `export default` part (you can have only one `default export` in a file)

```
connect(mapStateToProps, Actions)(componentB)
connect(mapStateToProps, Actions)(componentC)
```

Comment: you should put this lines just before  `export default connect(mapStateToProps, Actions)(componentA)`

Comment: for more infos check this link of a [github issue on the redux repo](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/647#issuecomment-285460734)

Comment: of course i did, i also tried to put it in useEffect but nothing happened

Comment: You should do it like @MarikIshtar said and also instead of using `export default ...`, use `export const`, like this: `export const ReduxContainerA = connect(mapStateToProps, Actions)(componentA); export const ReduxContainerB = connect(mapStateToProps, Actions)(componentB); export const ReduxContainerC = connect(mapStateToProps, Actions)(componentC);`